# Bundling with pyinstaller - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4

Tags: python, bundle

After I finish making my Python script, I’d like to bundle my script and the libraries used and I could spread my script more easily.

I tried to do with with PiInstaller but I run my script generated on the dist folder, I get that the module bs4 (beautifullSoup is not found)

**I proceeded as follows :**

I run the piInstaller from my virtual environment directory that I created with the command “python3 -m venv env » as bellow :

```
$ /home/kfocal/.local/bin/pyinstaller podcast_apple.py                                 
31 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2 
31 INFO: Python: 3.8.5 
39 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.4.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 
42 INFO: wrote /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/podcast_apple.spec 
45 INFO: UPX is not available. 
47 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths 
['/home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env', 
'/home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env'] 
54 INFO: checking Analysis 
54 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 
54 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 
55 INFO: Caching module graph hooks... 
58 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict. 
60 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... 
2102 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'. 
2103 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.8' 
4053 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 
4137 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc 
4160 INFO: Analyzing /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/podcast_apple.py 
4235 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-six.moves.py'. 
5794 INFO: Processing module hooks... 
5794 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'... 
5796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'... 
5949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
5952 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util 
5952 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
5954 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
5955 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util 
5955 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util 
5955 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6004 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6011 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6024 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib 
6024 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6025 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle 
6025 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6027 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq 
6027 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6064 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'... 
6080 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs 
6104 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ... 
6107 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py' 
6111 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_certifi.py' 
6121 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries 
6500 INFO: Looking for eggs 
6500 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching... 
6546 INFO: Using Python library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 
6554 INFO: Warnings written to /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/build/podcast_apple/warn-podcast_apple.txt 
6582 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/build/podcast_apple/xref-podcast_apple.html 
6591 INFO: checking PYZ 
6591 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent 
6591 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/build/podcast_apple/PYZ-00.pyz 
7080 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/build/podcast_apple/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully. 
7084 INFO: checking PKG 
7084 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent 
7084 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg 
7126 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully. 
7127 INFO: Bootloader /home/kfocal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run 
7127 INFO: checking EXE 
7127 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent 
7127 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc 
7128 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/focal/Documents/python/Kdata/env/build/podcast_apple/podcast_apple 
7138 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully. 
7139 INFO: checking COLLECT 
7139 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent 
7140 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc 
7158 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

As you can notice, everything seems to be okay but I get that the bs4 module is missing

```
~/Documents/python/Kdata/env/dist/podcast_apple$ ./podcast_apple  
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "podcast_apple.py", line 1, in <module> 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' 
[81848] Failed to execute script podcast_apple
```

And when I search « bs4 », I can only found in the lib of my dev.

```
~/Documents/python/Kdata/env$ find . -name "*bs4*" 
./lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4 
./lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4-0.0.1.egg-info
```

Did I missed something ?
According the documentation, piInstaller is supposed to copy all the used modules. Why pyInstaller missed bs4 ? Mon script is very simple.

> To find out, PyInstaller finds all the import statements in your
> script. It finds the imported modules and looks in them for import
> statements, and so on recursively, until it has a complete list of
> modules your script may use.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is quite old, but I had this same issue when running PyInstaller from within my virtual environment. beautifulsoup4 was installed in my virtualenv, but still PyInstaller didn't seem to be adding the package. Adding `--hidden-import beautifulsoup4` when running PyInstaller did not solve the problem, either.

After much searching, I finally came across this link: https://groups.google.com/g/PyInstaller/c/0IOY5Xoevsg

The suggestion I saw:

> Could you run it *(PyInstaller)* as `python -m PyInstaller [rest of the command here]` (instead of running `pyinstaller.exe [args]`)?

This, surprisingly, did the trick for me. I think I now understand what was happening: I think that though I was in a virtualenv which had the package installed, the pyinstaller that was being invoked was in the wrong environment (outside my virtualenv?) - perhaps because of the sequence in which I activated the virtualenv.

> **Using `python -m ...` forces it to use the correct PyInstaller**

Even more:

> If `python -m PyInstaller` gives a No module named PyInstaller error
> **then your venv is a mess and PyInstaller is not in the correct
> environment**. Using `python -m ...` forces it to use the correct
> PyInstaller (which doesn’t exist). The PyInstaller in your PATH
> presumably is left over from some other old environment (use `where PyInstaller` to find out which) or your root environment.
>
> The fix is just to install PyInstaller in your venv using:
>
> `venv\Scripts\activate pip install PyInstaller`
>
> Verify that the 1st (or only) output from where PyInstaller now points
> inside your venv/Scripts.

**tl;dr** : In summary -

1. try running pyinstaller as `python -m PyInstaller [args]` rather than `pyinstaller.exe [args]`, to attempt to force it to use the correct context of pyinstaller
2. If that still doesn't work, install PyInstaller from *within the virtual env itself*, by running `pip install PyInstaller`

Hopefully this helps someone.